# how can I get the old value when updating the record using Ajax in laravel?

Tags: javascript, ajax, laravel

i tried every way to solve this problem but not worked properly  can someone help to solve this problem

**note this is my problem:** i want to get old value when the form is empty via updating the user details. help me to solve this problem

update part Codes in ajax

```
   function getUserId(id)
{
    $.get('/getUserId/'+id,function(response){
        
        $("#id").val(response.id);
        $("#name2").val(response.name);
        $("#email2").val(response.email);
        $("#gender2").val(response.gender);
        $("#editModel").modal('show');

        
    });
}

$('#editUserForm').submit(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();

  let id = $("#id").val();
  let name = $("#name2").val();
  let email = $("#email2").val();
  let gender = $("#gender2").val();
  let password = $("#password2").val();
  let email_verified_at = $("#verified_at2").val();
  let _token = $("input[name=_token]").val();

  $.ajax({
     url: "/updateUser",
     type:"PUT",
     data:{
         id:id,
         name:name,
         email:email,
         gender:gender,
         password:password,
         email_verified_at:email_verified_at,
         _token:_token,
     },
     success:function(response)
     {
        
         $('#editModel').modal('toggle');
         $('#editUserForm')[0].reset();
         table.ajax.reload();       
         

     }
    
  });
  
});
```

Controller..

```
public function getUserId($id)
{

    $user = User::findOrFail($id);
    return response()->json($user);

}

public function updateUser(Request $request)
{

    $updateUser = User::find($request->id);
    $updateUser->name = request('name');
    $updateUser->email = request('email');
    $updateUser->gender = request('gender');
    $updateUser->password = Hash::make(request('password'));
    $updateUser->email_verified_at = request('verified_at');
    $updateUser->save();
    return response()->json($updateUser);

}
```

this is my update user form...

```
<!-- Edit User --> edit user form


                <form id="editUserForm">
                    @csrf
                    <input type="hidden" name="id" id="id">
                <div class="col-lg-12"> 
                        <label class = "mdl-textfield__label ml-3 " >Name</label>
                  <div class = "mdl-textfield mt-4 mdl-js-textfield mdl-textfield--floating-label txt-full-width">
                     <input class = "mdl-textfield__input" type = "text" id = "name2" maxlength="20" minlength="3">
                     <label for="gender" class="mdl-textfield__label "></label>
                  </div>
                </div>
                 <div class="col-lg-12"> 
                        <label class = "mdl-textfield__label ml-3 " >Email</label>
                  <div class = "mdl-textfield mt-4 mdl-js-textfield mdl-textfield--floating-label txt-full-width">
                     <input class = "mdl-textfield__input" type = "email"  id = "email2" >
                     <label for="gender" class="mdl-textfield__label "></label>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-12"> 
                <label for="gender" class="mdl-textfield__label ml-3">Gender</label>
                  <div class="mdl-textfield mt-5 mdl-js-textfield mdl-textfield--floating-label getmdl-select getmdl-select__fix-height txt-full-width">
                        <input class="mdl-textfield__input" type="text"  required="" id="gender2" readonly tabIndex="-1">
                         <label for="gender" class="mdl-textfield__label "></label>
                        <label for="gender" class="pull-right margin-0">
                            <i class="mdl-icon-toggle__label material-icons">keyboard_arrow_down</i>
                        </label>
                        <ul data-mdl-for="gender" class="mdl-menu mdl-menu--bottom-left mdl-js-menu">
                            <li class="mdl-menu__item" data-val="DE">Male</li>
                            <li class="mdl-menu__item" data-val="BY">Female</li>
                        </ul>
                        <span class = "form-line"></span>

                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-12"> 
                <label class = "mdl-textfield__label ml-3 " >Password</label>
                  <div class = "mdl-textfield mt-4  mdl-js-textfield mdl-textfield--floating-label txt-full-width">
                    <input class = "mdl-textfield__input" type = "password" name="password"  maxlength="15" minlength="8"  id = "password2">
                     <label for="gender" class="mdl-textfield__label "></label>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-12 "> 
                    <label class = "mdl-textfield__label ml-3 " >Verified_at</label>
                       <div class = "mdl-textfield mt-4 mdl-js-textfield mdl-textfield--floating-label txt-full-width">
                          <input class = "mdl-textfield__input" type = "date"  id="verified_at2">
                           <label for="gender" class="mdl-textfield__label "></label>
                       </div>
                </div>
                 <div class="col-lg-12 p-t-20 text-center"> 
                    <button type="submit" class="mdl-button mdl-js-button mdl-button--raised mdl-js-ripple-effect m-b-10 m-r-20 btn-pink" id="addUser" >Submit</button>
                    <button type="button" class="mdl-button mdl-js-button mdl-button--raised mdl-js-ripple-effect m-b-10 btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
                 </div>
             </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just store the last values to some object and then pass the object to the controller.